# "App not installed" when trying to install over existing debug apk

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, flutter

When two or more developers work in a team, they can't overwrite the installed APK if it is generated by the other developers. This is the exact scenario:

1. Two developers are working on same Android project.
2. When developer one generates and shares debug APK. its getting installed on device and runs properly.
3. When developer two generates the debug APK with same codebase and try to install app over app shared by
   developer one it shows message as "App not installed".
4. When developer one again share debug APK then it gets installed over the existing app.

Can anyone tell why this error occurs is there any laptop level dependency is there?

Comment: I think on locally you need to uninstall app first and then install another APK.

Comment: that helps but I want to know the reason?

Comment: you have to uninstall  the first app to install the other one. why? coz conflicts of fingerprints and signature etc..

Comment: the reason is both are using different machines. so while generating APK, it uses different signatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why this happens

This happens because the app you are building on Android is being signed with a specific keystore that is generated on your local machine. So when developer 1 signs the app with his keystore, it gets his fingerprint and you can install it fine. But when developer 2 builds the app with his (different) keystore, it gets a different fingerprint. Therefore Android won't let you overwrite the app that was already installed. **The solution** would be to share the debug keystore so the fingerprints of all APK's will align.

The keystore can be found in `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

### How to verify

You can verify the fingerprint of your APK's with the following command: `keytool -printcert -jarfile app.apk`, or `keytool -printcert -jarfile app.aab` in case you output an aab.

Comment: both computers must have the same ~/.android/debug.keystore. Just copy one on another

Comment: Exactly, as I've already mentioned in my answer: "The solution would be to share the debug keystore."

Answer (score 0):

Before generating debug APK, Android Studio automatically signs your app with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. So both the APKs are signed with different keys.

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode)